# How can I print size of array for meta_data?

Tags: woocommerce

I want to print size of array for meta_data. Following is an object of items:

```
array(1){
  [
    8
  ]=>object(WC_Order_Item_Product)#3734(11){
    [
      "extra_data": protected
    ]=>array(9){
      [
        "product_id"
      ]=>int(0)[
        "variation_id"
      ]=>int(0)[
        "quantity"
      ]=>int(1)[
        "tax_class"
      ]=>string(0)""[
        "subtotal"
      ]=>int(0)[
        "subtotal_tax"
      ]=>int(0)[
        "total"
      ]=>int(0)[
        "total_tax"
      ]=>int(0)[
        "taxes"
      ]=>array(2){
        [
          "subtotal"
        ]=>array(0){

        }[
          "total"
        ]=>array(0){

        }
      }
    }[
      "data": protected
    ]=>array(11){
      [
        "order_id"
      ]=>int(17616)[
        "name"
      ]=>string(10)"Alex check"[
        "product_id"
      ]=>int(17477)[
        "variation_id"
      ]=>int(0)[
        "quantity"
      ]=>int(1)[
        "tax_class"
      ]=>string(0)""[
        "subtotal"
      ]=>float(960)[
        "subtotal_tax"
      ]=>string(1)"0"[
        "total"
      ]=>float(960)[
        "total_tax"
      ]=>string(1)"0"[
        "taxes"
      ]=>array(2){
        [
          "total"
        ]=>array(0){

        }[
          "subtotal"
        ]=>array(0){

        }
      }
    }[
      "cache_group": protected
    ]=>string(11)"order-items"[
      "meta_type": protected
    ]=>string(10)"order_item"[
      "object_type": protected
    ]=>string(10)"order_item"[
      "id": protected
    ]=>int(8)[
      "changes": protected
    ]=>array(0){

    }[
      "object_read": protected
    ]=>bool(true)[
      "default_data": protected
    ]=>array(11){
      [
        "order_id"
      ]=>int(0)[
        "name"
      ]=>string(0)""[
        "product_id"
      ]=>int(0)[
        "variation_id"
      ]=>int(0)[
        "quantity"
      ]=>int(1)[
        "tax_class"
      ]=>string(0)""[
        "subtotal"
      ]=>int(0)[
        "subtotal_tax"
      ]=>int(0)[
        "total"
      ]=>int(0)[
        "total_tax"
      ]=>int(0)[
        "taxes"
      ]=>array(2){
        [
          "subtotal"
        ]=>array(0){

        }[
          "total"
        ]=>array(0){

        }
      }
    }[
      "data_store": protected
    ]=>object(WC_Data_Store)#3736(4){
      [
        "instance": "WC_Data_Store": private
      ]=>object(WC_Order_Item_Product_Data_Store)#3737(3){
        [
          "internal_meta_keys": protected
        ]=>array(20){
          [
            0
          ]=>string(9)"_order_id"[
            1
          ]=>string(5)"_name"[
            2
          ]=>string(11)"_product_id"[
            3
          ]=>string(13)"_variation_id"[
            4
          ]=>string(9)"_quantity"[
            5
          ]=>string(10)"_tax_class"[
            6
          ]=>string(9)"_subtotal"[
            7
          ]=>string(13)"_subtotal_tax"[
            8
          ]=>string(6)"_total"[
            9
          ]=>string(10)"_total_tax"[
            10
          ]=>string(6)"_taxes"[
            11
          ]=>string(11)"_product_id"[
            12
          ]=>string(13)"_variation_id"[
            13
          ]=>string(4)"_qty"[
            14
          ]=>string(10)"_tax_class"[
            15
          ]=>string(14)"_line_subtotal"[
            16
          ]=>string(18)"_line_subtotal_tax"[
            17
          ]=>string(11)"_line_total"[
            18
          ]=>string(9)"_line_tax"[
            19
          ]=>string(14)"_line_tax_data"
        }[
          "meta_type": protected
        ]=>string(10)"order_item"[
          "object_id_field_for_meta": protected
        ]=>string(13)"order_item_id"
      }[
        "stores": "WC_Data_Store": private
      ]=>array(18){
        [
          "coupon"
        ]=>string(24)"WC_Coupon_Data_Store_CPT"[
          "customer"
        ]=>string(22)"WC_Customer_Data_Store"[
          "customer-download"
        ]=>string(31)"WC_Customer_Download_Data_Store"[
          "customer-session"
        ]=>string(30)"WC_Customer_Data_Store_Session"[
          "order"
        ]=>string(23)"WC_Order_Data_Store_CPT"[
          "order-refund"
        ]=>string(30)"WC_Order_Refund_Data_Store_CPT"[
          "order-item"
        ]=>string(24)"WC_Order_Item_Data_Store"[
          "order-item-coupon"
        ]=>string(31)"WC_Order_Item_Coupon_Data_Store"[
          "order-item-fee"
        ]=>string(28)"WC_Order_Item_Fee_Data_Store"[
          "order-item-product"
        ]=>string(32)"WC_Order_Item_Product_Data_Store"[
          "order-item-shipping"
        ]=>string(33)"WC_Order_Item_Shipping_Data_Store"[
          "order-item-tax"
        ]=>string(28)"WC_Order_Item_Tax_Data_Store"[
          "payment-token"
        ]=>string(27)"WC_Payment_Token_Data_Store"[
          "product"
        ]=>string(25)"WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT"[
          "product-grouped"
        ]=>string(33)"WC_Product_Grouped_Data_Store_CPT"[
          "product-variable"
        ]=>string(34)"WC_Product_Variable_Data_Store_CPT"[
          "product-variation"
        ]=>string(35)"WC_Product_Variation_Data_Store_CPT"[
          "shipping-zone"
        ]=>string(27)"WC_Shipping_Zone_Data_Store"
      }[
        "current_class_name": "WC_Data_Store": private
      ]=>string(32)"WC_Order_Item_Product_Data_Store"[
        "object_type": "WC_Data_Store": private
      ]=>string(18)"order-item-product"
    }[
      "meta_data": protected
    ]=>array(3){
      [
        0
      ]=>object(WC_Meta_Data)#3751(2){
        [
          "current_data": protected
        ]=>array(3){
          [
            "id"
          ]=>int(93)[
            "key"
          ]=>string(130)"pantalone ($890.00)"[
            "value"
          ]=>string(1)"1"
        }[
          "data": protected
        ]=>array(3){
          [
            "id"
          ]=>int(93)[
            "key"
          ]=>string(130)"pantalone ($890.00)"[
            "value"
          ]=>string(1)"1"
        }
      }[
        1
      ]=>object(WC_Meta_Data)#3752(2){
        [
          "current_data": protected
        ]=>array(3){
          [
            "id"
          ]=>int(94)[
            "key"
          ]=>string(125)"Shoes ($40.00)"[
            "value"
          ]=>string(1)"1"
        }[
          "data": protected
        ]=>array(3){
          [
            "id"
          ]=>int(94)[
            "key"
          ]=>string(125)"Shoes ($40.00)"[
            "value"
          ]=>string(1)"1"
        }
      }[
        2
      ]=>object(WC_Meta_Data)#3753(2){
        [
          "current_data": protected
        ]=>array(3){
          [
            "id"
          ]=>int(95)[
            "key"
          ]=>string(123)"Cap ($30.00)"[
            "value"
          ]=>string(1)"1"
        }[
          "data": protected
        ]=>array(3){
          [
            "id"
          ]=>int(95)[
            "key"
          ]=>string(123)"Cap ($30.00)"[
            "value"
          ]=>string(1)"1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please anyone can help me to figure out. I tried to figure out with the following function:

```
function custom_cnt_items($items) { 
    $order = wc_get_order( 17616 );
    $items = $order->get_items(); 
    $arr = []; 
    foreach($items as $k => $obj) { 
        $arr[] = $obj; 
    } 
    foreach($arr[0] as $k => $v) { 
        foreach($v as $a => $b) { 
            echo $a . $b; 
        } 
    } 
    wp_die(); 
}
```

But is not working in Wordpress functions.php file…

Comment: I try to figure out by following function not working in wordpress functions.php
function custom_cnt_items($items) {
   $order = wc_get_order( 17616 );
   $items = $order->get_items();
   $arr = [];
        foreach($items as $k => $obj) {
              $arr[] = $obj;
            
        }
        foreach($arr[0] as $k => $v) {
            foreach($v as $a => $b) {
                echo $a . $b;
            }
        }
   wp_die();
   
}

Comment: Please edit your post rather than chucking a gob of unformatted code in a comment.

Comment: Your question is unclear… Why you want to print the size of order line item array? what do you want to do with it? You should "Edit" your question, instead of adding code in comments. Also the hook of your function is missing…

Comment: add_action('init','custom_cnt_items'); I want to customize pdf file and print total no of subitems

Comment: I m just tesing , how to access that meta_data array, Please help

Answer (score 0):

I could not access meta_data object property directly by using object because it is protected. I have to use some woocommerce methods inside that particular class to retreive data that in array format.